# Is If-Modified-Since strong or weak validation?

Tags: http

HTTP 1.1 states that there can be either *strong* and *weak* `ETag`/`If-None-Match` validation. My questions is, is `Last-Modified`/`If-Modified-Since` validation strong or weak?

This has implications whether sub-range requests can be made or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-23.html#rfc.section.4.3:

"A response might transfer only a subrange of a representation if the connection closed prematurely or if the request used one or more Range specifications. After several such transfers, a client might have received several ranges of the same representation. These ranges can only be safely combined if they all have in common the same strong validator, where "strong validator" is defined to be either an entity-tag that is not marked as weak (Section 2.3 of [Part4]) or, if no entity-tag is provided, a Last-Modified value that is strong in the sense defined by [Section 2.2.2](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p4-conditional-23.html#lastmod.comparison) of [Part4]."

Answer (score 1):

An ETag can be strong or weak depending on its suffix. Normally it will be strong, except if you access dynamic content where the content management system (CMS) handles that which is IMHO very uncommon.

However, the `If-Modified-Since` headers result should be strong too if and only if nobody manipulates the metadata of the files in the filesystem. In Linux it is pretty simple with the touch command, however I think you normally don't need to care about that. If somebody manipulates your server you have a different problem entirely.